# bias and variance of correlation estimator

Tags: correlation, sample, bias

I calculated the bias and variance of sample mean $\hat{\mu}$ and sample variance $\hat{\sigma}^2$ but I could not calculate the bias and variance for sample correlation $\hat{\rho}$. How can I do the calculation? Can you give me some references, textbooks, articles about it?

Edit: by sample correlation I mean 
$$ \hat{\rho}_{xy} = \frac{\sum_{i} x_i y_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i}x_i^2 \sum_{i}y_i^2}}      $$

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by bias, and/or how you calculated it?

Comment: By bias I mean the difference between the estimator's expected value and the true value of the parameter being estimated

Answer (score 1):

A basic into text should give the variance (is this what you mean?):
$\sigma^{2}_{\rho}=\frac{1-\rho^{2}}{n-2} \approx \frac{1-\hat{\rho}^{2}}{n-2}$

Fisher addresses the bias: Fisher, R.A. (1915). Frequency distribution of the values of the correlation coefficient in samples from an indefinitely large population. *Biometrika*, 10, 507-521.

For a fuller treatment see: Zumbo, B. D., Williams, R. H., and Zimmerman, D. W. (2003). Bias in estimation and hypothesis testing of correlation. *Psicológica: Revista de metodología y psicología experimental*, 24(1):133– 158.

Comment: In fact, I mean sample correlation between two variables x, y

Comment: @Alexis good answer. Is there any bias in rho ρ ? If it is there, please explain to me.

Comment: @neticin look at the *last* term of my equation on the first line, that's the *sample* correlation.

Comment: @Alexis can you point me a textbook where I can find this one because I didn't understand why the first equality is true

Comment: Sure: Glantz, S. A. (2005). *primer of biostatistics*. McGraw-Hill Medical, New York, NY, 6th edition.