# Weird correlation between two variables

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression

I have a dataset with one continuous dependent variable $y$ and a set of explanatory variables $x_i$.

I am first analyzing the correlation between $y$ and every $x_i$ through a matrix correlation plot.

One of these explanatory variables ($x_2$) is giving me a correlation of 0.0384 which apparently explains a low correlation.

However, watching the plot, I can see that two distinct groups are plotted.

[image: correlation matrix]

Is there any way to modify this variable ($x_2$) to perform a better correlation? Or should I discard this variable from the model because it does not explain $y$?

Maybe generating new computed variables from $x_2$?

Comment: X2 appears to be bimodal and has near-zero correlation with Y. Any linear transformations you do won't affect the Pearson correlation, and any monotonic transformation will have no effect on the Spearman correlation. Transformations aren't going to do much to help you find a better correlation here, unless you're doing some kind of non-linear, non-monotonic transformation, which would be a bit unusual unless you have a good reason to be doing it.

Comment: @NuclearWang $X_2$ is defined as wind direction (I think measured in degrees). Then you think I should discard this variable ?

Comment: If either variable is a direction, Pearson's correlation makes no sense as it ignores the circular nature of any scale on which $0^\circ \equiv 360^\circ$. The way to look for relationships is to use sine and cosine of direction as predictors. I don't see much evidence of dependence on direction but that is the way to move forward, Two modes about half-a-circle apart would usually arise from topographic situation, e,g, winds up and down valley, winds on and offshore.

Comment: There is nothing weird about the correlation. It answers one question only: how well could these data be summarized by a straight line? You get a bonus answer, the sign of the slope of that best fit line.

Comment: "explains" in your question would be (much) better as "indicates".

Comment: Ah, then a non-monotonic transformation does make sense here, as a value of 359 is closer to 0 than it is to 350. @NickCox is correct, a sine/cosine transformation would be appropriate for a variable that represents angular degrees around a circle.

Comment: I have generated new predictors as $sin(x_2)$ and $cos(x_2)$ but correlation between these new two variables and $y$ seems to be very low yet (0.0181 and 0.00458)

Comment: That is often true. Even with climatic responses, direction may have only a secondary effect. As you haven't said what your response is, it is hard to say more. By the way, this may be obvious and good if so, your data may come as degrees but in most software sine and cosine functions expect to be fed arguments in radians,

Comment: I think the plot from 0 to 360 might be splitting in half a third group of points at the 0-to-360 boundary. You can verify this by re-plotting with an overlap in that region as a quick check.

Comment: The density function estimate is also wrong at each end. It's not fair to expect a general purpose routine to have a switch for different kinds of variables, but the density estimation should wrap around, so that the density estimate just E of N takes account of values just W of N, and conversely. That has a little bearing on @James Phillips's suggestion, although I don't guess at a strong third mode myself.

Comment: I've consolidated my comments as an answer. I haven't deleted them above because that would make the discussion harder to understand.

Comment: A useful trick is to hit each marginal variable with an empirical probability integral transform (`ecdf(x1)(x1)` in R) and plot the transformed variables against each other. If they are independent, this plot should just fill up the unit square. If there is a pattern, there is some sort of dependence structure. This gets at something called a copula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing weird about the correlation. It answers one question only: how well could these data be summarized by a straight line? You get a bonus answer, the sign of the slope of that best fit line. The scatter plot makes it clear: no straight line could work well to summarize the entire relationship. The grouping of points is interesting and important but makes no difference to that fact.

The predictor concerned is revealed to be wind direction, measured in degrees from North presumably.

If either variable in a correlation is a direction, Pearson's correlation makes no sense as it ignores the circular nature of any scale on which $0^\circ \equiv 360^\circ$. Another way to see this: if there is a relationship between direction and a response, it must be such that the prediction is identical at $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$, as these are the same direction. The only straight line which satisfies that would be a horizontal line, meaning no relationship at all, so that the best-fit line is just the mean of the response.

The way to look for relationships is to use sine and cosine of direction as predictors. I don't see much evidence of dependence on direction, but that is the way to move forward.

A geographical or climatological comment: Two modes about half-a-circle apart would usually arise from topographic situation, for example, winds up and down valley (anabatic and katabatic) or winds on and offshore.

The OP reports generating  new predictors as sine and cosine, but correlations between these two new variables and the response seem to be very low. That is often true. Even with climatic responses, direction may have only a secondary effect. As you haven't said what your response is, it is hard to say more.

The density function estimate is also wrong at each end. It's not fair to expect a general purpose graphical routine to have a switch for different kinds of variables, but the density estimation should wrap around, so that the density estimate just East of North takes account of values just West of North, and conversely. That is not hard to program, but in my experience requires code tailored to directional variables rather than being provided by general density estimation routines.

Answer (score 1):

As a guide to the analysis of correlation relationships in your database, I refer one to this [comment on the proper use](https://influentialpoints.com/Training/Pearsons_correlation_coefficient_use_and_misuse.htm) (or misuse) of Pearson’s correlation coefficient, to quote:

> If a parametric test of the correlation coefficient is being used, assumptions of bivariate normality and homogeneity of variances must be met. We give several examples where these assumptions are clearly not met - for example variables such as mortality rates and body condition scores are very unlikely to resemble a normal distribution. Moreover body condition score is an ordinal rather than a measurement variable - so again a non-parametric correlation coefficient would have been more appropriate.
>
> Perhaps more important is whether the relationship really is linear. We give several examples where the relationship is instead curvilinear - for example the relationship of the percentage of late stage mature female fish to rainfall, and the relationship of the number of eagles to the number of fish. In another example an 'outlier' is omitted from the analysis in order to make the relationship linear. Non-linear but monotonic relationships should instead be analyzed using a non-parametric correlation coefficient. Another very important issue is whether the bivariate observations really are independent. Ecologists and epidemiologists commonly use the correlation coefficient to assess spatial or temporal relationships, and in such studies observations may be either spatially or temporally autocorrelated. We look at several examples of this including a study relating solar radiation in a state to the incidence of colon cancer, a study relating abundance of the small blue butterfly in a habitat to abundance of its foodplant, and a study relating reproductive traits of fish over time to environmental characters. In all these cases (and several others) the coefficient is likely to be biased towards unity giving a spurious correlation.

Relatedly, with respect to the discussion of correlation and causality, the following comments:

> Yet (ignoring random variation) many apparent relationships could easily result from confounding factors - for example in the study relating the incidence of inflammatory bowel disease to a proxy variable for poverty. The apparent inverse relationship could just result from people in wealthier countries being more informed about the disease and being more ready to report symptoms, especially for a disease which does not automatically hospitalize or kill. Remarkably few authors rigorously apply the generally accepted criteria for causality to the matter at hand. In one example we even see evidence of bias in selection of observations in an attempt to demonstrate a relationship which may simply not exist - the relationship between homicide rates and suicide rates is wildly unconvincing to all but the author.

The same source also provides a good list of source references in the Section "What the statisticians say", which I would strongly recommend.

Note, the variance of the sample correlation coefficient itself, at times, can be a contributing factor, (see prior [comment by Alexis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96987/bias-and-variance-of-correlation-estimator) on StackExchange).